# JMeter - HTTP2 Request doesn't save MD5 hash

Tags: jmeter, md5, http2, jmeter-plugins

I'm submitting HTTP2 Request and checking `Save response as MD5 hash?`

Tried both in `HTTP2 Request` and `HTTP2 Request Defaults`, but response isn't MD5, just show normal response

I tried to view it using listeners: `View Result Tree Http2` and `View Result Tree`

Is it working somehow or is it a missing?

- Note after checking checkbox inside `HTTP2 Request` and focus on other element and return, the checkbox is off

Also I tried changing protocol to http and it's ignored (use https)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot save response data as MD5 hash due to the [asynchronous nature of the responses](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-http2-plugin#limitations), if for some reason you want the response hash you can tick `Synchronized Request` box and use i.e. [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) or [__digest() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest) to calculate the hash of the response for later reuse
2. I don't think you can use HTTP protocol as HTTP2 sampler relies on [alpn-boot](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/alpn-chapter.html) library which [assumes TLS transport](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7301)

More information: [The New HTTP/2 Plugin for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-http2-plugin-for-jmeter-the-complete-guide/)